# My Error: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am fetching data from api struct with this error. i checked many website for reference but i dint get proper solution

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://stock.adverscribe.in/api/controllers/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public
static Retrofit getClient() {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

ApiInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("getMenu")
Call<MenuResponse> getMenuResult();
}
```

MainActivity .java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MenuResponse> call = apiService.getMenuResult();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MenuResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MenuResponse> call, Response<MenuResponse> response) {
            int code = response.body().getCode();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MenuResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

this is the json data

```
{
"code": 200,
"message": "SUCCESS",
"data": {
    "menu": [
        {
            "division": {
                "stock_division_id": "1",
                "stock_division_name": "Men",
                "stock_division_status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-01-12 11:59:00",
                "updated_date": "2018-01-12 11:59:22"
            },
            "cat": [
                {
                    "stock_category_id": "1",
                    "stock_division_id": "1",
                    "stock_category_name": "T-Shirts",
                    "stock_category_status": "1",
                    "created_date": "2018-01-12 12:00:14",
                    "updated_date": "2018-01-12 12:00:14"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "division": {
                "stock_division_id": "2",
                "stock_division_name": "Women",
                "stock_division_status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-01-12 11:59:44",
                "updated_date": "2018-01-12 11:59:44"
            },
            "cat": [
                {
                    "stock_category_id": "2",
                    "stock_division_id": "2",
                    "stock_category_name": "T-Shirts",
                    "stock_category_status": "1",
                    "created_date": "2018-01-12 12:02:24",
                    "updated_date": "2018-01-12 12:02:24"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Error stack

```
 01-23 18:34:14.219 13628-13628/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
 01-23 18:34:14.544 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.adverscribe.myapplication-2/lib/arm
 01-23 18:34:14.567 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
 01-23 18:34:14.687 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
 01-23 18:34:14.998 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
 01-23 18:34:15.123 13628-13650/com.adverscribe.myapplication I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : ead2395, I23cc4685e6
                                                                   Build Date                       : 04/11/17
                                                                   OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.04
                                                                   Local Branch                     : 
                                                                   Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r5-rel
                                                                   Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                   Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
 01-23 18:34:15.137 13628-13650/com.adverscribe.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 01-23 18:34:15.137 13628-13650/com.adverscribe.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
 01-23 18:34:15.170 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
 01-23 18:34:15.205 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ca6d04c time:134394442
 01-23 18:34:16.628 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=134395859, downTime=134395859, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 } to DecorView@67df74[MainActivity]
 01-23 18:34:16.630 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication I/AudioManagerEx: AudioManagerEx created
 01-23 18:34:16.709 13628-13628/com.adverscribe.myapplication I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=134395942, downTime=134395859, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 } to DecorView@67df74[MainActivity]
```

Comment: show full error stacktrace. And also show JSON that you try to parse.

Comment: json data stacktrace added to question please have a look

Comment: there is no exception stacktrace in your provided log. Please give an exception stacktrace.

Comment: as @dave mentioned, your API returns some junk in addition to JSON, which makes the response an invalid JSON. Make your API return JSON before you continue.

Answer (score 1):

Your api is not returning valid JSON

```
stdClass Object([stock_division_id] => 1[stock_division_name] => Men[stock_division_status] => 1[created_date] => 2018 - 01 - 12 11: 59: 00[updated_date] => 2018 - 01 - 12 11: 59: 22) stdClass Object([stock_division_id] => 2[stock_division_name] => Women[stock_division_status] => 1[created_date] => 2018 - 01 - 12 11: 59: 44[updated_date] => 2018 - 01 - 12 11: 59: 44) {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "menu": [{
            "division": {
                "stock_division_id": "1",
                "stock_division_name": "Men",
                "stock_division_status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-01-12 11:59:00",
                "updated_date": "2018-01-12 11:59:22"
            },
            "cat": [{
                "stock_category_id": "1",
                "stock_division_id": "1",
                "stock_category_name": "T-Shirts",
                "stock_category_status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-01-12 12:00:14",
                "updated_date": "2018-01-12 12:00:14"
            }]
        }, {
            "division": {
                "stock_division_id": "2",
                "stock_division_name": "Women",
                "stock_division_status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-01-12 11:59:44",
                "updated_date": "2018-01-12 11:59:44"
            },
            "cat": [{
                "stock_category_id": "2",
                "stock_division_id": "2",
                "stock_category_name": "T-Shirts",
                "stock_category_status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-01-12 12:02:24",
                "updated_date": "2018-01-12 12:02:24"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: can i know what is the problem with the api

Comment: This: stdClass Object([stock_division_id] => 1[stock_division_name] => Men[stock_division_status] => 1[created_date] => 2018 - 01 - 12 11: 59: 00[updated_date] => 2018 - 01 - 12 11: 59: 22) stdClass Object([stock_division_id] => 2[stock_division_name] => Women[stock_division_status] => 1[created_date] => 2018 - 01 - 12 11: 59: 44[updated_date] => 2018 - 01 - 12 11: 59: 44) is not JSON